# How can I get a single column of output from the bdf command on HP-UX?

Tags: hp-ux

I would like to monitor disk space usage. I'm using HP-UX and the `bdf` command.

I would like to check one directory and I can do that: `bdf /exploit/`

[image]

I would like to get only the row **%used**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

for /exploit only

```
bdf /exploit | awk 'NR==2 { printf "%d\n",$5 ;}
```

for any filesystem

```
bdf | awk '{printf "%3d %s\n",$5,$6}'
```

note

- you can use `%s` instead of `%d` to get back `%` sign...
- or use `%d %%`